# Configuring version number in beam file

Tags: erlang

How do I set the version number of a compiled module in Erlang? There's a version number in each `.beam` file, and I am modifying modules in each release of my project. Can I configure this version number in my releases?

Comment: Modules can be given versions? Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erlang builds the `vsn` attribute into modules automatically. If it is not set by you, it defaults to the MD5 of the file.

You can set it by including it in your module:

```
-vsn("MY VERSION").
```

To check which version your module has, use [`beam_lib:version/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/beam_lib.html#version-1).

For example, if you're using SVN you could set it to `"$Rev$"` for SVN to automatically substitute it for the current version. With Git, this could be achieved with [keyword expansion](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion).